# Scale change properties in $R^n$ for a kinetic energy functional

Tags: integration, physics, mathematical-physics

I'm working on a project and for it I needed to read and understand a paper by Berestycki-Lions about the existence of Nonlinear Scalar Field equations. (If someone has it or is further interested in the context its page $319$ in Section $2$ *Necessary  Conditions*.) 
Anyway, the thing is at some point it says:

We define fhe functional $T(u)$:
$$T(u) = \int_R^N |\nabla u|^2\, dx $$
one readily checks that it has the property that for a scale change in $R^N$: for $\sigma > 0$ we define $u_\sigma (x) = u(x/ \sigma)$:
$$T(u_\sigma) = \sigma^{N-2} T(u).$$

My problem is, I don't really see how this works, so any help will be very much appreciated. I don't know if it's necessary for the proof but u is furthermore spherically symmetric.

Comment: For $\LaTeX$ read [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelGaluza!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume your integral is over all $R^N$ and $\nabla u=\partial u/\partial x$ is a vector in $R^N$. Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
T(u_\sigma) &= \int_{R^N} |\nabla u_\sigma(x)|^2\, dx 
= \int_{R^N} |\nabla u(x/\sigma)|^2\, dx 
= \int_{R^N} \left|{\partial u(x/\sigma)\over\partial x}\right|^2\, \sigma^N d(x/\sigma)\\
&= \int_{R^N} \left|{\partial u(x/\sigma)\over\sigma \partial (x/\sigma)}\right|^2\, \sigma^N d(x/\sigma)
= \sigma^{N-2} \int_{R^N} \left|{\partial u(x/\sigma)\over\partial (x/\sigma)}\right|^2\, d(x/\sigma)=\sigma^{N-2}T(u).
\end{aligned}
$$
For the case you mention in the comment below:
$$
\begin{aligned}
T(u_\sigma)(x) &= \int_{R^N} \left|{u_\sigma(x)-u_\sigma(y)\over|x-y|^{N+s}}\right|^2\, dy 
= \int_{R^N} \left|{u(x/\sigma)-u(y/\sigma)\over\sigma^{N+s}|x/\sigma-y/\sigma|^{N+s}}\right|^2\, \sigma^N d(y/\sigma) \\
&=\sigma^{-N-2s}\int_{R^N} \left|{u(x/\sigma)-u(y/\sigma)\over|x/\sigma-y/\sigma|^{N+s}}\right|^2\, d(y/\sigma)=\sigma^{-N-2s}T(u)(x/\sigma).
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks @Aretino!
On the same note, do you possibly know if there is some kind of similar identity if the functional is the fractional Laplacian? That is:

$$ T(u) = \int_{R^N} |\frac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^{N+s}}|^2 dy$$

Comment: In this case you have an explicit dependence on $x$, so you can't have the same scaling behaviour as above. You should consider instead $T(u)(x/\sigma)$ vs $T(u_\sigma)(x)$ and proceed as above.

Comment: Can you please elaborate any further? I don't really understand how to proceed, though I see that I will not obtain something similar...

Comment: @Laia see what I've just added to my answer.